# How to locate a application XML file in the Server side of a JSP project?

Tags: java, jsp, xml-parsing, webserver

I am new at web program.
At the back-end, we use Java,and I add a xml file used by application in "/src/main/resources/xxx.xml"
The question is how can I locate this file dynamicly？？

For example, I wrote:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/xxx.xml");
```

But "is" is always a null object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From the directory structure shown, I would guess that you are using Maven to perform the building, etc. If this is the case, files placed in src/main/resources can be found at the root of your class hierarchy.

So, something like this probably what you're looking for:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("xxx.xml");
```

Comment: Are you running your application through an IDE? If so, is the IDE configured to work with Maven? (ie. make sure your IDE has the resources directory set as a source folder)

Comment: Yes,we are using Maven.And there is a "resource" directory under main folder